# How to Peek the Lowest elements from a List of sorted Streams continously

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, priority-queue

I started learning about Java Stream, and I am wondering is it possible to only peek the first element of the stream without retrieving it.

For example, I have multiple streams, and each of them have integers that are sorted in non-decreasing order, and I want to get a sorted list of all integers, so I'm thinking about using a `PrioirtyQueue<Stream>` sorted in non-decreasing order as well.

However, in order to get the `PrioirtyQueue<Stream>` to sort the streams, I need to pass in a comparator for stream to compare streams by their first element, and I am not sure how to peek the first element in each stream.

For example, I have the following streams.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5],
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

I want to write a function `getNextInteger()`, that handles a list of **sorted streams**.

Every time I call the method, it returns the next smallest integer, so the result might be `[0,1,2,2]` if I call the method `4` times.

I want to use `PriorityQueue` to sort the streams by their first value, and retrieve the smallest one and requeue the stream if it is not empty.

Comment: It sounds as though you are expecting the PriorityQueue to reorder its contents as you mutate them. I don't think standard implementations will do that. Or is it the case that if the first element of a stream is smaller than the first element of another stream, *all* the elements of the first stream will be smaller than all elements of the second stream?

Comment: The short answer is: No.  It is not possible to do that.

Comment: updated the question to be more exact. thanks!

Comment: `it returns the next smallest integer` - without executing any of these streams. It's impossible. You need a custom `Iterator` not a queue of streams.

Comment: I see. how would a custom ```Iterator``` look like to handle multiple streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream is a mean of iteration over the source of data, it's meant to process the data, not to store it.

Therefore, your question is inherently incorrect. The short answer is no.

It's not a data structure, you can't access elements in a *stream* in the same way as elements in a `List` or in a `Queue`.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities,
> have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the
> efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast,
> **streams do not provide** a means to directly **access** or **manipulate** their
> **elements**, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing
> their source and the computational operations which will be performed
> in aggregate on that source.

As I said, *stream* is a mean of iteration, but stream pipeline also differs from the `Iterator`. An `Iterator` allows retrieving elements one by one. Conversely, a *stream pipeline* will be either executed and produce a result (as a single value or a collection of values) and will be closed, or will not be executed. It will depend on whether stream has a terminal operation or not.

For instance, this *stream* is valid, it will compile fine, but it will not get executed:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c").map(String::toUpperCase);
```

Because it lacks a terminal operation.

Every *stream* should have a *source* and a single *terminal operation* which triggers the execution of the pipeline and produces the result. Intermediate operations like `map()` and `filter()`, which are meant to transform the stream, are optional.

You can't obtain the data from the *stream* without processing it. And once it's processed, it can no longer be used.

As a possible remedy for this problem, you might consider wrapping the stream with an object that will maintain separately the first element from the stream source and the stream itself.

```
public record StreamWrapper(int first, IntStream stream) {}
```

That approach can be used, it will be sufficient to compare streams by a single value, which should be extracted from the stream source (*if the stream source allows that*) at the same time when the stream gets generated.

---

#### Update

> I want to write a function getNextInteger(), that handles a list of
> **sorted streams**.
>
> Every time I call the method, it returns the next smallest integer, so
> the result might be `[0,1,2,2]` if I call the method `4` times.

That task in not suitable for streams. Unless you can blind on the fact that the data in every stream is already sorted.

If we combine all the streams in one and apply sorting, it will not cause a gigantic performance hit as it might seem at the beginning. In order to sort the data stream dumps all the elements into an array which in this case will be comprised of sorted subarrays. Because an array of a reference type will be sorted using [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), the algorithm implementation will spot all these sorted chunks. I.e. sorting the array composed of partially sorted subarrays isn't the same as sorting all these data from scratch. Hence, we can consider it as a possible option:

```
List<Stream<Integer>> streams =
List.of(Stream.of(1, 3), Stream.of(5), Stream.of(2, 6, 7),
        Stream.of(4, 9, 10), Stream.of(8));
        
streams.stream()
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .sorted()
    .forEach(num -> System.out.print(num + " "));
```

Will produce an output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If printing (*or storing into a collection*) the overall data sorted in ascending order doesn't seem satisfactory, and you insist on retrieving only a single value as a result of method invocation, I'll reiterate that it's impossible to fetch values one by one continuously from a stream.

For that you need an `Iterator` as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) suggests:

> However, if the provided stream operations do not offer the desired functionality, the `BaseStream.iterator()` and `BaseStream.spliterator()` operations can be used to perform a controlled traversal.

You can implement a `custom iterator` that will utilize a `PriorityQueue` under the hood.

I assume that streams are of type that implements `Comparable` and streams are sorted (*like in the example you've provided*).

*Iterator:*

```
public class QueueBasedIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Queue<IteratorWrapper<T>> nextValues = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private List<Iterator> iterators = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public StreamBasedIterator(Stream<T>... streams) {
        this.iterators = Stream.of(streams).map(Stream::iterator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < iterators.size(); i++) {
            Iterator<T> iterator = iterators.get(i);
            if (iterator.hasNext()) 
                nextValues.add(new IteratorWrapper<T>(i, iterator.next()));
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !nextValues.isEmpty();
    }
    
    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (nextValues.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        
        IteratorWrapper<T> next = nextValues.remove();
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterators.get(next.getPosition());
        if (iterator.hasNext())
            nextValues.add(new IteratorWrapper<T>(next.getPosition(), iterator.next()));
        
        return next.getValue();
    }
}
```

*IteratorWrapper:*

```
class IteratorWrapper<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<IteratorWrapper<T>> {
    private T value;
    private int position;
    
    public IteratorWrapper(int position, T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.position = position;
    }
    
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(IteratorWrapper<T> o) {
        return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
    }
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    QueueBasedIterator<Integer> iterator =
        new QueueBasedIterator<>(Stream.of(1, 3), Stream.of(5), Stream.of(2, 6, 7),
                                 Stream.of(4, 9, 10), Stream.of(8));
    
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: if I wrap each stream in an object that maintain the first value, how do I get the first value? as you said I need to process the stream to get the value, what if each stream has like millions integers, Im not sure I want to process all of them to get the first int? thanks!

Comment: @Sammy Added the example of the record that will store the first value from the source and the stream separately.

Comment: Okay I see. afaik iterator only works on its stream, how do I handle multiple stream and make sure the integer that Im getting the the smallest one among the stream? Or are you suggesting that I do a PrioirtyQueue<Iterator> ?

Comment: @Sammy I'm not completely getting your question. I'm *not* suggesting to operate on a single stream, you might be confusing me with WJS. I've provided a demo where iterator take as an input a *number of sorted streams* and processes them. Please, take a look at it and clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering is it possible to only peek the first element of the stream without retrieving it.

No.  `Peek` is an `intermediate operation`, like `map, sort`, etc. They do not cause the stream to start delivering data. To do that requires a `terminal operation` such as `reduce, forEach, or collector`, etc to start the streaming process.

This also allows one to do things like the following with out storing any data.  If it did, the first statement (`series`) would never finish as it would require infinite storage since there is no limiting method.

```
IntStream series = IntStream.iterate(0, i->i+1);
IntStream first10 = series.limit(10);
int[] toArray = first10.toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toArray));
```

Prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In the above example, `toArray()` is the terminal operation that starts the stream.  Once finished, the stream is exhausted and none of the aforementioned assignments (e.g. `series, first10`) may be used again.

Comment: I see. it makes sense to deal with one stream like that! Is it possible to deal with multiple streams that could have millions of integers in each of them, and combine the result as each stream is being processed?